# How to count Major peaks only in excel

Tags: excel

I am doing a project using accelerometers and have collected large volumes of readings.  I need to find acceleration spikes.  I used a previous formula I found

=SUMPRODUCT(--(N3:N586>N2:N585),--(N3:N586>N4:N587))

The range of values is N2:N587, how this counts every peak, so even if a sensor reading jumps up and down I get a count. Is there a way to adapt this to count major peaks some like PEAK = cell value is greater than the preceding or following 3,4 or 5 cell values.
as an example
0.01, 0.02, 0.015, 0.018, 0.015, 0.014, 0.016, 0.02, 0.017, 0.018, 0.014,
in this sample I want to count 0.02 as a Major peak, but not the 0.018 as minor peaks.

I can do it if I plot as a graph and manually count, but for some recordings I have over 3000 values I have to expand the graph quite a lot to count them.
any help would be great thanks

Comment: Depends on the data there seems to be a lot of way you can solve this case. 
For example if the data is not trending up or down (assume time series). Then a simple frequency distribution analysis can solve your case. However if the data is trending up or down, you can always try to normalize the data before identifying the peak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA and check, if the cell value is greater than a threshold. Yet you don't need VBA, you can use another column and just write an `IF`-Statement to check, if a threshold is exceeded. If so, return `TRUE`. Then count all `TRUE` values using `COUNTIF`. Or you can directly use `COUNTIF` and check for thresholds.

For instance:
Using this formula should return the total number of values above 150 in your range: `=COUNTIF($N$3:$N$586;">150")`. Please note: The cell references are absolute values. The formula returns a total number, not the sum. Adapt the range and the threshold as you need.

Comment: I have originally used this formula, the threshold is 2 standard deviations above the mean.  The sequence of readings occur at 100ms intervals as they so the trouble with the countif method was that it counts all the values over the threshold rather than just the peaks, so I get a reading for all the values upto and down from the peak.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an offset formula to check whether the current reading is greater than the previous and next n readings:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(($A$2:$A$12>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$1,ROW($A$2:$A$12)-B2-1,0,B2)))*
($A$2:$A$12>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$1,ROW($A$2:$A$12),0,B2))),0))
```

Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

The required offset is stored in B2.

I have tried it with a range of offsets as below:

[image]

As you can see, when the offset is increased to 6, you get no peaks because the second peak of 0.02 is equal to the first peak of 0.02. This does highlight a potential snag with this approach, that if you got a genuine peak or plateau with (say) two consecutive values of 0.02, it wouldn't be counted. But if your actual data has several decimal places this probably won't happen.

It's possible for this formula to give a spurious peak at the end of the range because it counts values beyond the range (i.e. A13, A14 etc.) as zeroes - the formula could be further refined to avoid this.

Comment: I'll try this, the readings are to 5 decimal places so is unlikely I should have 2 exactly identical values.  They are a series of recordings every 100ms

Comment: 0.015305, 1, 233,   0.011095, 1, 227;
0.006552, 2, 156,   0.008772, 2, 154;
0.014581, 3, 130,   0.005375, 3, 131;
0.0037, 4, 102,   0.003986, 4, 95;
0.020475, 5, 69,   0.0115, 5, 84;
0.005743, 6, 60,   0.003093, 6, 72;
0.000857, 7, 54,   0.007251, 7, 63;
0.038007, 8, 48,   0.005717, 8, 56;
0.052214, 9, 42,   0.003689, 9, 47;
0.031168, 10, 42,   0.008156, 10, 44;
0.00023, 11, 41,   0.000782, 11, 39;
0.012474, 12, 37,   0.009697, 12, 39;
0.003486, 13, 33,   0.009906, 13, 36;
0.009725, 14, 31,   0.001166, 14, 33;
0.030517, 15, 29,   0.01169, 15, 33;

Comment: Can't work out how to post up a spreadsheet example, the array works, seems reasonable to set the offset to about 10.

Comment: Is it possible to set a second parameter - must be a peak value + must be above a threshold, then it should be counted?

Comment: Yes, you can just add a condition like this =SUM(($A$2:$A$12>0.015)*(IFERROR(($A$2:$A$12>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$1,ROW($A$2:$A$12)-B2-1,0,B2)))*($A$2:$A$12>SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET($A$1,ROW($A$2:$A$12),0,B2))),0)))

Comment: I also realized I could change the range to A:A and then I don't have to modify the formula for each spreadsheet as for each person the range of values is more or less depending on how long they took to complete the task